# How to disable Enter button for code snippet in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

Sometimes when I press the Enter button, VSCode will aggressively complete the code which I don't want.

For example:

When I type in the

```
import numpy as np
```

and press the enter, VSCode will change the `np` to `numpy`

or when I type in the

```
else
```

and press the enter, VSCode will change it to

```
else
{
    /*...*/
}
```

while I sometimes really don't need this format.

So how can I disable 'Enter' for code snippet and use Tab only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by going to your settings and search for `Accept Suggestion On Enter` in the search bar. Simply toggle it to `off` and this should solve your problem.[image]

Comment: The same thing happens when I fill the placeholder of a snippet with a value that triggers another snippet upon pressing tab. How can this be avoided?